# Why was this VLQ flag declined despite the post being deleted?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Yesterday I flagged [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181842/are-there-any-vibroswords-or-vibroblades-in-the-star-wars-movies/184921#184921) as VLQ (10k link). My flag was declined with:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

However, given that it has since been deleted by review, someone else clearly flagged it VLQ, then it passed through the review queues wherein 5 other users agreed.

So why was my flag declined? And why with that specific message, which does not seems to apply in this case.

Comment: I can't see the answer but if it has a negative score, three 20K users can vote to delete it. Has nothing to do with review queues, though.

Comment: It says "deleted from review 21 hours ago by...."

Comment: It probably should not have been deleted, at least going by previous discussions and policy, where even this barebones attempt at an answer is still considered a valid attempt.  That said, I don't really understand the current answer here either.

Answer (score -14):

Read the decline reason.

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

though I could also have used

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Since it was deleted from the review queue it clearly didn't need mod intervention.

And note the text of the flag:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

It could have been improved, e.g. by adding examples.

As I've said before, VLQ is very rarely a useful flag, especially for posts already in the LQ queue and should really be removed.

Comment: It was a VLQ flag, that shouldn't have required direct mod intervention.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the second decline reason I quoted says. If it doesn't require mod intervention, it shouldn't be a flag.

Comment: Flags are also "Send to review queue" actions. Close, NAA, RO are also all actions that are handled in the queues and don't need mod intervention.

Comment: That post **does have** severe content problems.

Comment: Surely when flagging for moderator intervention one would use the “***in need of moderator intervention***” flag.